# Макрос в vim, добавляющий точку с запятой в конец строки

Tags: vim

Как написать в *vim* макрос, добавляющий точку с запятой в конец строки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В командной моде `:map ; A;<ESC>`.

Comment: спасибо, я буду пользоваться именно этим

Comment: ок, если можно, еще вот что: сделать на клавишу z забиндить cout << " тут будте курсор";

Comment: я попробовал сделать это так:     
map z acout<<'""<ESC>h
но выводится почему-то 
cout<<'''<ESC>h 
-то есть переход в нормальный режим через <ESC> не срабатывает, в отличие от 
:map ; A;<ESC>
-здесь все работает как нужно

Comment: окей, дело было в символе "меньше"(<) его нужно представить в таком виде <lt>(less-then). итого готовая команда -         map z acout<lt><lt>""<ESC>i                 PS можно набрать в виме :help key-notation там будут все таблицы таких специальных символов